# Obtaining the accurate plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting attenuation in db/km versus frequency.
 The corresponding equation is

```
α'(dB / km) = 3.3× 10−3 + ((0.11*f^2)/(1+f^2)) + ((43*f^2)/(4100+f^2)) + 2.98*10^-4*(f^2)
```

The required graph [image]

and Mat lab [image]

outputs are as shown. What can I do so as to get the exact output as shown in fig?

Comment: The `y` axis is on a logarithmic scale as well.  Your plot only shows a linear scale for the `y` axis. You should probably include whatever code you wrote to produce that plot.  BTW, we apologize for not seeing this question as it has been over a year since you asked.  However, you did not tag your question with MATLAB (looks like someone just added it) so none of the usual users who answer in MATLAB will have seen your question on the MATLAB feed.  Please ensure you add all necessary tags to your question before posting.